# No visible @interface for [object] declares the selector [method]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a complete beginner at Objective c and I am trying to complete a challenge in the book "iOS programming: The big Nerd Ranch guide".

I'm trying to put an object called **item** (of the class BNRItem) into an NSMutableArray called **subItems** which is part of an object called **container** (of the class BNRContainer, a subclass of BNRItem with the addition of the NSMutableArray to hold BNRItems). BNRItem works fine.

The code is as follows:

BNRContainer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRContainer : BNRItem
{
NSMutableArray *subItems;
}
```

BNRContainer.m

```
- (id)init
{
return [self initWithItemName:@"Container"
               valueInDollars:0
                 serialNumber:@""];
}

- (void)setSubItems:(BNRItem*)item
{
[subItems addObject:item];
}
```

Main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"
#import "BNRContainer.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    BNRItem *item = [[BNRItem alloc] init];

    BNRContainer *container = [[BNRContainer alloc] init];

    [container setSubItems:item]

    }

return 0;
}
```

At the line **[container setSubItems:item]** I get the error: *No visible @interface for container declares the selector setSubItems*

The setter method setSubItems doesn't code complete (although other setters do, and work fine).

Am I doing something simple wrong? A simple explanation would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update BNRContainer.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRContainer : BNRItem
{
    NSMutableArray *subItems;
}
- (void)setSubItems:(BNRItem*)item;
@end
```

(Dunno why Fred deleted his answer.)

Comment: I think he (Fred) may have slightly misread the question (although his answer was very helpful to me none the less). Your answer solves the problem perfectly - I was just over looking something simple (declaring it in the .h file). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In order for Xcode to generate the getters/setters for subItems, you have to actually declare the property for it in your interface. Something like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRContainer : BNRItem
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *subItems;
@end
```

Additionally, you aren't ever actually alloc/initing your array, and the current logic for setSubItems: will not do what it sounds like it would do. This function would add the array passed as a parameter as an object within SubItems. If you're trying to add items from an array to subitems, then you should be using:

```
[myMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:<#(NSArray *)#>];
```

Comment: without an explicit `@synthesize subItems = subItems` the property will not use the ivar. better to get rid of the ivar entirely

Comment: Actually, all he has to do is to declare setSubItems in his .h.  No need to use `@propery` at all.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why Fred deleted his post.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helps a lot with not just this question. I think Hot Licks' answer is a simpler solution for my specific problem, if anyone is reading this later.

Comment: @ 0x7fffffff ah sorry - tried to upvote it but it wouldn't let me. Didn't realise the tick was clickable. Thanks for the pointer!